# I installed unity tweak tool but cant find it in dash

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I installed unity tweak tool in the terminal but i cant find it to run in my dash. does anyone know how to run it

Comment: Unity Tweak Tool is a regular GUI tool, no need to run it from cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Unity-Tweak-Tool is normaly not a CLI tool you should be able to find it in Dash after a logout/reboot, but if not simply run it from terminal:

```
unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: Unity Tweak Tool is a regular GUI tool, why run it from cli?

Comment: I had that myself it doesnt show up in the dash, after i had run it from terminal it was aswll in dash but before not.

Comment: Then a simple log out/in would have done thye job as well :). You might want to make clear in your answer you don't mean to *always* run it from cli.

Comment: Revised my answer based on your input.

Answer (score 2):

Simply putting 'Tweak' in the Dash should be enough:

[image]

Comment: It wont show up right after it was installed, I think that's the problem :)
Logging out and back in or rebooting loads the corresponding .desktop files into Dash.